# Implementing generic interface with generic method

Tags: c#, generics

I've got interface as follows:

```
public interface IService<T> where T : class
{
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAsync<U>(int subscriberId, U request) where U : SearchRequestBase;
}
```

I'm implementing the following way (CategoriesRequest inherits SearchRequestBase):

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<CategoriesResponse>> GetAsync<CategoriesRequest>(int subscriberId, CategoriesRequest request)
{
    // Implementation
}
```

But no matter what I do, I get compile errors, the only way to make it work was to put U generic in interface and put constraint there.

Is this recommended way to do it? Or can I declare generic method with constraint next to my method and implement it that way?

My intention is to put generic only as a return type and my input has to contain anything that inherits from `SearchRequestBase`.

#### Update

So this is my base class:

```
public class SearchRequestBase
{
    private const int minimumQueryLength = 3;
    private const int minimumResultsSize = 1;
    private const int maximumResultsSize = 100;
    private const int defaultResultsSize = 5;

    protected SearchRequestBase()
    {
    }

    [Required]
    [MinLength(minimumQueryLength, ErrorMessage = "Query string has to contain at least three characters")]
    public string Query { get; set; }

    [Range(minimumResultsSize, maximumResultsSize, ErrorMessage = "Size must be between 1 and 100")]
    public int Size { get; set; } = defaultResultsSize;
}
```

And `CategoriesRequest` class that now does not yet implement any extra properties (but will).

```
public class CategoriesRequest : SearchRequestBase
{
}
```

There are more requests that inherit from SearchRequestBase.

So now there's my `IService` interface:

```
public interface IService<T> where T : class
{
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAsync(int subscriberId, SearchRequestBase request);
}
```

And I implement it in `CategoryService`:

```
public class CategoryService : IService<CategoriesResponse>
{
    private readonly IElasticClient _client;

    public CategoryService(IElasticClient client)
    {
        _client = client ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(client));
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<CategoriesResponse>> GetAsync(int subscriberId, CategoriesRequest request)
    {
        var descriptor = new CategoryBuilder().Build(subscriberId, request);

        var index = "categories";

        var response = await _client.SearchAsync<CategoriesResponse>(descriptor.Index(index));

        return response.Documents;
    }
}
```

However compiler curses at me and gives the following error:

```
Error   CS0535  'CategoryService' does not implement interface member 'IService<CategoriesResponse>.GetAsync(int, SearchRequestBase)'
```

Comment: It's rarely right (in my experience) for a generic interface to have methods that are additionally generic (declare additional type parameters). In your example, you're expecting a class to be able to commit to returning a `CategoriesResponse` for *any* type that inherits from `SearchRequestBase`? Because that's what your interface definition seems to imply.

Comment: Can you provide more context? It'd help to see the declaration of the class that contains your implementation.

Comment: Also you are using `CategoriesRequest` as a generic type name, that's probably confusing you too.

Comment: if `U` is supposed to be of `SearchRequestBase` type then why not `Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAsync(int subscriberId, SearchRequestBase request)`?

Comment: So what you *probably* want is: `public interface IService<T, U> where T : class where U : SearchRequestBase { Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAsync(int subscriberId, U request); }`

Comment: @Corak No need for that if you use the line from vikscool, especially if `SearchRequestBase` is an abstract class.

Comment: @DavidG - yes, if the information/functionality from `SearchRequestBase` suffices. *Maybe* OP wants additional information/functionality special to `CategoriesRequest` in that specific implementation.

Comment: ... or maybe not: "input has to contain anything that inherits from `SearchRequestBase`." - so ignore my point. ^_^;

Comment: @JohnWu This is a simple search service that is used to query Elasticsearch. I'll update my question with more details.

Comment: @vikscool I've tried as you suggested, but it complains :)

Comment: Your method signature needs to be `public async Task<IEnumerable<CategoriesResponse>> GetAsync(int subscriberId, SearchRequestBase request)` otherwise you need to add another generic type parameter to the interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method signature needs to be:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<CategoriesResponse>> GetAsync(
    int subscriberId, SearchRequestBase request)
```

Otherwise you need to add another generic type parameter to the interface. For example:

```
public interface IService<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : SearchRequestBase
    where TResponse : class
{
    Task<IEnumerable<TResponse>> GetAsync(int subscriberId, TRequest request);
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought as well. Thanks David